# Setting Callout options globally

Tags: labeling

When I do
`SetOptions[Callout,CalloutStyle->Red]` and then do `Plot[Callout[x^2],{x,-3,3}]`, I get plot with a regular gray (not red) callout marker. Can I not set those options globally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another work-around: Use `SetOptions` for `Plot` to set the option value for `PlotLabels`:

```
SetOptions[Plot, 
  PlotLabels -> Callout[Automatic, Automatic, CalloutStyle -> Red]];

Plot[x^2, {x, -3, 3}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[{x^2, 5 + x^2, 10 - 4 x}, {x, -3, 3}]
```

[image]

Comment: That'll do...thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

A workaround:

```
calloutopts = Sequence[CalloutStyle -> Red];

Plot[Callout[x^2, x^2, calloutopts], {x, -3, 3}]
```

[image]

Comment: Weird.  I wonder why that works and the naive, direct way does not... that the global option setting does not work.

Comment: Your answer is essentially what I've been doing. I'll hold out for a bit to see if anyone has a way to make the global setting work before accepting this as answered. Thank you.